# Multiplying two tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the two tensors in Tensorflow, which have the following two shapes:

```
print(tf.valid_dataset.get_shape())
print(weights1.get_shape())
```

Has the result:

```
(10000, 784)
(784, 1024)
```

However, if I try to multiply them, like this:

```
tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights1)
```

I get:

```
Tensor("Variable:0", shape=(784, 1024), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Const:0", shape=(10000, 784), dtype=float32).
```

Since I am multiplying them on the side where they both have the size `784`, this seems correct to me.

Any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT:

The code I have before the print statements is this:

```
num_hidden_nodes=1024
batch_size = 128
learning_rate = 0.5

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size*image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf.valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset) 
    tf.test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, num_hidden_nodes]))
    biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_hidden_nodes]))
    weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden_nodes, num_labels]))
    biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))
    weights = [weights1, biases1, weights2, biases2]

    lay1_train = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights1) + biases1)
    logits = tf.matmul(lay1_train, weights2) + biases2
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf_train_labels))

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Comment: from the error, it looks like the two tensors live in different graphs (maybe you loaded one model from a checkpoint while some other code is defined in the same script?)

Comment: Please add details about how you created tf_valid_dataset and weights1 variable. The following code works
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.random_normal([10000, 784], mean=0, stddev=1)
    weights1 = tf.random_normal([784, 1024], mean=0, stddev=1)
    result = tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights1) #it works

Comment: What do you mean by different graphs?

Comment: Each time in tensorflow you create a node, this is associated to a tf.Graph object https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph . Usually, a default graph is understood, and all nodes are appended to this default graph. But in some situations, more than one graph may exist, and you can combine only operations in the same graph

Comment: Now I see the edits, it looks everything is in the same graph... `tf.valid_dataset` is a typo, right? (a dot `.` instead of an underscore `_`)

Comment: your code works fine on my compiler (I replaced the valid and test data I don't have with tf.zeros)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Please check again. 
Verify it by running the below code:

```
num_hidden_nodes=1024
batch_size = 1000
learning_rate = 0.5
image_size = 28
num_labels = 10


tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size*image_size))
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
# tf.valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset) 
# tf.test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, num_hidden_nodes]))
biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_hidden_nodes]))
weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden_nodes, num_labels]))
biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))
weights = [weights1, biases1, weights2, biases2]

lay1_train = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights1) + biases1)
logits = tf.matmul(lay1_train, weights2) + biases2
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf_train_labels))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
input_data = np.random.randn(batch_size, 784)
input_labels = [np.random.randint(0,10) for _ in xrange(batch_size)]

import sklearn.preprocessing
label_binarizer = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
transformed_labels = label_binarizer.fit_transform(input_labels)



sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={tf_train_dataset:input_data, tf_train_labels:transformed_labels})
```

Comment: What have you changed that's relevant?

Comment: No significant changes, can you share your whole code so that I would run it locally and resolve all the issues.