# How to add biases to neural network layer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two `tf.Variable`:

```
data_entries_times_weights1
biases1
```

They have the shapes:

```
(10000, 1024)
(1024,)
```

However, when I multiply them like this:

```
lay1_valid = tf.nn.relu(data_entries_times_weights1 + biases1)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Tensor("Variable:0", shape=(784, 1024), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Const:0", shape=(10000, 784), dtype=float32).
```

From what I saw on Github, people are adding biases in a similar manner, like: `data_entries_times_weights1 + biases1`.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: It's correct. The problem is that `data_entries_times_weights1` is defined in a graph while `biases1` is defined in another graph

Comment: Can you show the whole code?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757650/multiplying-two-tensors

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

I am receiving the following error message

```
ValueError: Tensor("Variable:0", shape=(784, 1024), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Const:0", shape=(10000, 784), dtype=float32).
```

and I'm trying to do something like

```
lay1_valid = tf.nn.relu( data_entries_times_weights1 + biases)
```

where :

- input is Const(10000, 784 )
- weights is Variable( 784 , 1024 )
- bias is Variable( 1024, )
- data_entries_times_weights1 = input * weights

## Solution

Most likely **data_entries_times_weights1** is equal to input.  Double check that data_entries_times_weights1 is

```
data_entries_times_weights1 = tf.matmul( input , weights )
```

Comment: did this answer your question?